# Problems renaming PDFs directly on GitHub

Tags: git, github, rename, file-rename

I need to modify the name of a PDF file in a private GitHub repository. I cannot clone the repo because the problems are due to some special characters I would like to eliminate.

Following the instruction contained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.20/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/renaming-a-file), it is possible to rename every kind of file but PDF. Specifically, for PDF files, the button `edit file` does not exist.

Is there a way of renaming the file directly on GitHub?

Comment: *"Some files, such as images, require that you rename them from the command line."* - PDFs too, presumably.

Comment: right. So I cannot pull because of special characters like `>` and there is nothing I can do. I am stuck

Comment: Yes. You may be able to get help from GitHub support but there's nothing you or we can do.

Comment: On Windows 10, you can use WSL for this because it doesn't have the Windows restrictions when working in your WSL home directory.

Comment: @bk2204, I use Xubuntu 20.04. There were no problems with 16.04. However, after the update, there are. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413692/error-unable-to-create-file-invalid-argument-once-again-but-for-linux-based

Comment: What file system are you operating on?  Is it FAT or NTFS?  Running `stat -f .` in the repository should show you.